# Configure slf4j-log4j12 rollover based on time and size

Tags: java, apache, slf4j, log4j

I am using slf4j-log4j12 for logging. Logging configuration is stored in "log4j.properties" as below. I am using size based rollover using "RollingFileAppender".

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=service.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz} [%t] %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Now I want time based rollover along with size based. Is there any way to specify time and size based rollovers in "log4j.properties" file?

Answer (score 0):

> Configure slf4j-log4j12 rollover based on time and size

```
Roll over by time: 
log4j.appender.serverAccess=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.serverAccess.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm
DatePattern to enable rollover every minute

Roll over by size : 
log4j.appender.serverAccess=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
maximum of 204800 KB (200 MB)
```

Also you can find more description for your question on this [link](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-configure-log-rolling-by-time-and-size)

Comment: Is there difference between log4j.appender.file and log4j.appender.serverAccess?